# Adding visual style to PHP scripts(pages)

Tags: php, html, css

The user arrives on the following php script and it sets if the email has been confirmed or not.

At the moment the only thing the user can seen in the browser is a very simple message printed by the php echo.

I would like it to look visually more interesting. Get this echo to be part of  a properly styled HTML page with header, font styles, signature, images...

What would be the best approach for that having in mind my script has breakpoints? As I never did that before, not sure what would be the best start point to focus the effort on.

> Bellow are my code updates based on the answers. Hope that helps other
>   users that are new to php.

```
<?php
require("../db/MySQLDAO.php");
require ("../Classes/EmailConfirmation.php");
$config = parse_ini_file('../db/SwiftApp.ini');

//host access data

$dbhost = trim($config["dbhost"]);
$dbuser = trim($config["dbuser"]);
$dbpassword = trim($config["dbpassword"]);
$dbname = trim($config["dbname"]);

// receive token data

$emailToken = htmlentities($_GET["token"]);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Title here</title>
<style>
/* -------------------------------------
        GLOBAL
------------------------------------- */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1.6;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
body {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    width: 100%!important;
    height: 100%;
}
/* -------------------------------------
        ELEMENTS
------------------------------------- */
a {
    color: #348eda;
}
.btn-primary {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #348eda;
    border: solid #348eda;
    border-width: 10px 20px;
    line-height: 2;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
.btn-secondary {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #aaa;
    border: solid #aaa;
    border-width: 10px 20px;
    line-height: 2;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
.last {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.first {
    margin-top: 0;
}
.padding {
    padding: 10px 0;
}
/* -------------------------------------
        BODY
------------------------------------- */
table.body-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
}
table.body-wrap .container {
    border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
}
/* -------------------------------------
        FOOTER
------------------------------------- */
table.footer-wrap {
    width: 100%;    
    clear: both!important;
}
.footer-wrap .container p {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #666;

}
table.footer-wrap a {
    color: #999;
}
/* -------------------------------------
        TYPOGRAPHY
------------------------------------- */
h1, h2, h3 {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    color: #d63480;
    margin: 40px 0 10px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-weight: 200;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 28px;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 22px;
}
p, ul, ol {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
}
ul li, ol li {
    margin-left: 5px;
    list-style-position: inside;
}
/* ---------------------------------------------------
        RESPONSIVENESS
------------------------------------------------------ */
/* Set a max-width, and make it display as block so it will automatically stretch to that width, but will also shrink down on a phone or something */
.container {
    display: block!important;
    max-width: 600px!important;
    margin: 0 auto!important; /* makes it centered */
    clear: both!important;
}
/* Set the padding on the td rather than the div for Outlook compatibility */
.body-wrap .container {
    padding: 20px;
}
/* This should also be a block element, so that it will fill 100% of the .container */
.content {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
/* Let's make sure tables in the content area are 100% wide */
.content table {
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#f6f6f6">

<!-- body -->
<table class="body-wrap" bgcolor="#f6f6f6">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="container" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

            <!-- content -->
            <div class="content">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h1>Title</h1>                      
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="padding">
                                    <p>
                                        <?php
                                        if(empty($emailToken))  {
                                            echo "<h2>Sorry, something went wrong...</h2>";
                                            echo "<p>Unfortunately your email validation token has expired.</p>";
                                            echo "<p>Please get in contact with us at <a href=mailto:></a></p>";

                                        }
                                        else{

                                            //open server connection

                                            $dao = new MySQLDAO($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbname);
                                            $dao->openConnection();

                                            //creates user 

                                            $user_id = $dao->getUserIdWithToken($emailToken);

                                            if(empty($user_id))
                                            {
                                                echo "<h2>Sorry, something went wrong...</h2>";
                                                echo "<p>We could not find an user associated with the email you provided.</p>";
                                                echo "<p>Please get in contact with us at <a href></a></p>";

                                            }
                                            else{

                                                $result = $dao->setEmailConfirmedStatus(1, $user_id);

                                                if($result)
                                                { 

                                                  echo "<h2>Thank you! Your email is now confirmed!<h2>";
                                                  $dao->deleteUsedToken($emailToken);  
                                                }

                                            }

                                            $dao->closeConnection();
                                        }
                                        ?>



                                    </p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <p class="padding"></p>
                        <p>Thanks,</p>
                        <p>Title team</p>
                        <p class="padding"></p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
            <!-- /content -->

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- /body -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you mean, echo header, body, css, etc... as an echo string. and inside the html string just place the variable I need to be dynamic? Could do that. Is it a good practice in PHP to have 3 long strings of of HTML inside a single PHP file just to echo with some HTML format?

Comment: I was not sure about doing that as it would build a chunk of repeated code. So that is how PHP devs do it then...

Is there a possibility to create a completely separated HTML file that just get an echoed string from a php file?

Comment: templating? there are as many approaches as developers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  [HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/html/) to structure your content and [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) to format your content.

You can echo HTML and CSS right along with your string.

Those links should get you going in the right direction.

## Update to accommodate comment

There are many methods, but a simple example that might work for your case is something like this:

Instead of `echo`ing right there in your `if` statement, replace it with an `include` or `require`.

Lets call that file `template.php`. This file does not need to start with `<?php` and end with `?>`. PHP can punch in and out with HTML. So `template.php` might look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="some_style"><?php
            echo 'something';
        ?></div>
        <div class="some_style2"><?php
            echo $some_var;
        ?></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also if this is going to be sent in an email, CSS is not really supported in email, so you will need to keep the styling to what you can do with simple HTML tags and images.

Comment: Will ask you the same I asked above: you mean, echo header, body, css, etc... as an echo string. And inside the html string just place the variable I need to be dynamic? Could do that. Is it a good practice in PHP to have 3 long strings of of HTML inside a single PHP file just to echo with some HTML format?

I was not sure about doing that. Is there a possibility to create a completely separated HTML file that just get an echoed string from a php file?

Answer (score 2):

Change your echo to:

```
echo '<div id="message">User with this email token is not found</div>';
```

Then style #message with css

Hope that helps!

Comment: Don't forget to escape the HTML `"`s.

Comment: or changed the echo to '...'. Good eyes!

Answer (score 2):

urgh.. uglyness html in php. There are ways in which you can include html within the script without echoing it out.

There is the old way.

```
// out of php
?>
<div>
<?php echo $content; ?>
</div>
<?
// back in.
```

Or you can look into php/html short hand. Your code will benefit from it because it will be somewhat cleaner to read,

The main reason though, dont make php parse html unless you have to.

Answer (score 0):

PHP

```
echo "<p id='token_message'>User with this email token is not found</p>";
```

CSS

```
#token_message {
    /* Styling Here */
}
```